# Problem with bubble tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bubble-popup

### Working live URL showing problem:

http://69.24.73.172/demos/newDemo/test.html

[image]
**The HTML**:

```
<div class="small-vote">
    <a href="#" class="s plus-one bubble" bubble=":)&lt;br /&gt;Vote this comment up&lt;br /&gt;if you like it!"></a>
    <a href="#" class="s minus-one bubble" bubble=":(&lt;br /&gt;Vote this comment down&lt;br /&gt;if you disagree with it!"></a>
</div>
```

This is a problem on all major browsers.  If the mouse enters the bottom halfish of the anchor link, it's all fine.  It highlights it, popup comes up, and you can click the link.

If you enter the top half of the link, it lets you click it until the mouse is moved even 1 pixel, then the link deactivates and you have to exit and re-enter the area to click on it.

It's enough of a problem to make the anchor links pretty unusable.

**The CSS**

```
a.bubble:hover
{
    background-color:Red;
}
.s{
    background-image:url('../images/sprites.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.plus-one
{
    display:block;
    width:20px;
    height:16px;
    background-position: -46px -135px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:1px;
    margin-top:1px;
}
.minus-one
{
    display:block;
    width:20px;
    height:16px;
    background-position: -67px -135px;
    float:right;
    margin-left:1px;
    margin-top:1px;
}
.minus-one:hover
{
        background-position: -67px -153px;
}
.plus-one:hover
{
    background-position: -46px -153px;
}
```

As a reference, when the popup box is taken off the anchor link, the links behave properly.  I'm using jQuery Bubble Popup v.2.3.1.

Comment: Try setting `line-height: 16px;`.

Comment: @Patrick, thanks for looking but that didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your tooltip is over the link! Check out the padding, maybe add some z-index to put it behind the link level =)

[image: Elements with border]

Comment: Thanks!  a.bubble
{
    position:relative;
    z-index:9999;
} This doesn't work though :(  The z-index of the popup is only 100

Comment: Change the class "jquerybubblepopup", change margin: 0px; to margin-top: -10px; to move it a bit .jquerybubblepopup { width: auto; height: auto; margin-top: -10px; [...] }

Comment: @Michael, thanks, works great!  But is there any way to position it also so it is nearer?  IE bring it's blue box in at the bottom

Comment: That is to say, I would like it if it could be back in it's original position, and have it's exterior padding removed to fix the bug